# Is there split() such as javascript or PHP

Tags: genexus

I'd like to send e-mail to the address that is enterd in a input form.
I could do if I enter one e-mail address in one form.
But I coludn't do when I enter to e-mail address in one form as add , between two addresses.

I'd like to keep that there is a input form.
So I'm finding split() of GeneXus or something like this for divide one string to some e-mail addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. It's called [SplitRegex](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?4606,Regular%20Expressions%20%28RegEx%29#SplitRegEx).

To split a comma separated string, you can do this:

```
&Result = &MyString.SplitRegex(",")
```

Where `&MyString` is a variable with a string like data type (`Character`, `VarChar` or `LongVarChar`) and `&Result` is a collection of a string like data type.